# Web service for sharing - and serving - php code?

Tags: web-apps, php, web-services, web-server

I am aware that there are services like

- http://ideone.com/1ae8DO/ -> http://ideone.com/plain/1ae8DO/
- http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e965-kbf2 -> http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/e965-kbf2

... where you can post a PHP snippet, get a unique URL id for it, and run it on the page itself - and even link to the raw source version of the code (as in the above example).

However, I am not aware of any such service, that also *serves* PHP code - say if my PHP code snippet is just `echo "test";` - then at some form of the URL with that ID I should get just the string `test` (the result of executing the PHP code). Apparently PHPFiddle had that once, as http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/e965-kbf2 responds with "This API was disabled as security reasons" - but it doesn't have it anymore.

So are there such services - where you can both post/share and run/serve PHP code - in existence? I simply need to write an example for a forum, where I can both share the code, and use the output in a JS example.. I would be OK if this service has limits on how many seconds the script is allowed to execute, or how much memory it is allowed to use...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there does seem to be a way with PhpFiddle APIs version 3.0 http://phpfiddle.org/deposit/phpfiddle_apis.php - but not with saved snippets; you can send the code in a POST request, and you will get a JSON encoded response (string output only).

So with `curl` in a Linux `bash` shell, one can do:

```
curl --data "phptag=yes" \
 --data-urlencode 'code=$a=array("One", "Two", "Three"); echo json_encode($a);' \
 http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/code/json
```

... and the response will be:

```
{"result":"[\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\"]"}
```

(It's slightly more difficult to do this with `wget`, since it doesn't urlencode its POST parameters)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer (the system will let you do so after two days), in order to help others who read this question in the future.